# Plywood Backed Drywall Equivalent to Studs for Hanging a TV?

Tags: walls, television

I need to mount a TV (~35lbs) to a wall without convenient access to a stud, but the wall in question happens to have a layer of 1/4" plywood on the back of the drywall. Possibly worth noting that it's held a ~25lbs iMac just fine for many years now, but I worry the larger TV might be the tipping point. Any thoughts about whether this will work or how I could safely assess it?

Comment: Is the plywood screwed to studs?

Comment: Flat mount or arm/extension mount?

Comment: manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: The plywood is screwed to studs and pretty secure. No concerns there.

Ecnerwal: Nothing has been bought yet, so could be either and definitely part of what I'm trying to think through. The iMac is on an extension arm, FWIW. Being able to pan at least a little would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were 1/2" plywood, I would have no concerns at all. With 1/4", it is a bit iffy. The plywood itself is relatively strong, particularly sandwiched between drywall and studs. The concern I have is whether the screws in the plywood have enough depth to grip well.

What would definitely work, if there is enough space behind the drywall/plywood, is [toggle bolts](https://amzn.to/32RLW3m):

[image: toggle bolt assortment]

This is a randomly selected assortment on Amazon, but you can get them from any hardware store. With drywall there is always a little concern you might hit a weak spot that was previously patched up. With plywood backing, toggle bolts can hold plenty of weight.

Comment: These anchors https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831 are far superior, not as fussy to install and will not fall into the wall if you undo the screw or un-mount the the TV mount.

Comment: That'll work too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **any** concerns then you should place a sheet of plywood on the mount side of the drywall. This piece of plywood should span to where you can find studs to secure it. If the secured stud span is less than about 24 inches (~ 60cm) then you should be ok with nominal 1/2" (12 or 13mm) thickness of plywood. Any spread of plywood securing distance greater than that should be 3/4" (18 or 19mm) thickness.

Plywood used in this manner spreads the load on the drywall across a wide area. This also puts the best screw retention material right next to the TV mount bracket. If the bracket is mounted right on drywall then there is a 1/2" (12 or 13mm) distance where the mount screws are not used in a pure sheer mode and can be twisted sideways in the soft gypsum material.

It can be even more beneficial if mount plywood has construction adhesive applied between the drywall and the back side of the plywood. This plywood can also be sanded to a fine finish and painted to match the wall surface so that it is hardly noticeable as an addition to the wall.